# $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left|f(g(t))-f(h(g(t)))\right| \,dt=0$ How to find $f$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, optimization

Let $h,g$ be given entire functions.
Consider

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|f(g(t))-f(h(g(t)))|\, dt=0,$$

where $|\cdot|$ means modulus.

How do I find non-polynomial analytic solutions for $f\,$?

How many possible solutions are there? How many degrees of freedom are there?

Comment: Thanks for the (small) Tex edit. @Clayton.

Comment: Isn't it the case that you simply need $f(z) = f(h(z))$ identically? My first intuition would be to write out what this condition says in terms of coefficients of $f$ and $h$, and see what comes out...

Comment: @Feanor Such an equation usually does not hold on the whole complex plane unless perhaps many singularities and special cases. In the sense of being true on a path I think you are correct. But looking at it in another way is not a solution yet. One of the reasons that f(z) = f(h(z)) does not hold everywhere per se is that it also implies f(z)=f(h(z))=f(h(h(z))))... by simple substition.

Comment: Is the condition about the integral equivalent to $f(g(t)) = f(h(g(t))$ for all reals $t$, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Feanor Yes you got that right I think. I think...

Comment: @mick: $f(z)=e^z$ and $h(z)=z+2\pi i$ would satisfy Feanor's condition.

Comment: @robjohn yes that is true. $h$ is an invariant of $f$ and that always works. What about the other cases ?

Comment: @Feanor: if $f,g,h$ are analytic, that would be enough to show that $f(g(z))=f(h(g(z)))$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @mick: my guess is that either $f(z)=f(h(z))$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ or $g(z)=h(g(z))$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @robjohn: I think you are almost correct. We have $f(g(z)) = f(h(g(z)))$ for all $z$ by analytic continuation (is that what you meant in a previous comment?), so $f(w) - f(h(w))$ has zeros at all values of $g$. So, either $g$ is constant, or $f(w) - f(h(w))$ has the set of zeros with a concentration point. So, $f(w) - f(h(w)) = 0$, unless $g$ is constant! (And $g = const$ is not a very interesting case ;)

Comment: If $f(w) = f(h(w))$, then $f$ is constant on orbits of $h$, in the sense that $f(h^k(w)) = f(w)$. I'm not quite sure, but I think for a generic $h$, the set of points where $f$ takes the value $f(w)$ will thus have an accumulation point...

Comment: @Feanor im sorry but the example robjohn gave is a counterexample to declaring $f(w)-f(h(w)) = 0$ everywhere(!) by analytic continuation !

Comment: @Feanor about your other comment , notice $h^k$ is a more restrictive requirement , I only used $h^1$. Basically your comment is a copy of my subtitution comment.

Comment: @mick: For invariance: Agreed, I should have read more thoroughly I suppose. For the counterexample: it seems to me that in this case $f(w) = f(h(w))$ because $e^{2 \pi i } = 1$. Or am I confused?

Comment: No your Ok , I mean that $f(w)-f(h(w)) = 0$ Does not imply an easy solution for $f$ , if $f$ is not $0$. Furthermore the analytic continuation might fail at a sufficient distance.

Comment: @mick: could you explain what you mean by "the analytic continuation might fail at a sufficient distance"?

Comment: @robjohn Well if $f(w)-f(h(w))$ is analytic then it must be analytic in the neighbourhood of the curve given by $w = g(t)$.
However outside this neighbourhood - aka at a sufficient distance - we might run into a singularity(or many), and hence there is no analytic continuation possible in that direction.